# create object from class name as string in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a model source (name, url, method)
The program parses the source's url for data. Now I have differen classes for parsing different types of urls: rss, xml, ogdata ...

So I have a common interface

> new(url) //Parses the url
>
> getTitle() //Get the title of the data
>
> getPrice() //Get the price

And I have four classes rss, xml, ogdata. These classes are in seperate files. The idea is to add more classes as I discover different types of pages. I want to initiate the right classes for the url.

method=source.method
//NOw I want to create a new class of the name specified in method

parser=Rss.new(source.url)//Instead of this
//Something like
parser=.new(source.url)

Comment: Give this a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302187/ruby-string-to-class-name

Answer (score 0):

You can try using const_get.

Ex:-

```
Kernel.const_get("YourClassNameHere").new
```

*Kernel.const_get("YourClassNameHere")* will get you the class. And you can use it to instantiate new instances of the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):081:0> User.name
=> "User"
```

then

```
"User".constantize.new(name: 'David')

or

User.name..constantize.new(name: 'David')
```