# Creating some class during tests (STI)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I have a class

```
Gate < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = :kindof
# some methods
end
#  and derived
MoneyHaters < Gate
# some overloaded methods
end
```

with type column :kindof for **STI**.

Durning tests I want to create a 2-3 childs. Mainly because each derived class must be unique in the app. Like that:

```
factory :gate do
  before(:create) do
    gate_name  = FFaker::Company.name.gsub( /\s+/,'' )
    gate_class_name = gate_name.singularize.classify
  end

  name { gate_name }

  # I want that next class will be declared in App namespace, like all others.
  gate_class  = Class.new(Gate) do
    def comission_in(amount)
      amount * 0.01 + 5
    end
    def comission_out(amount)
      amount * 0.02 + 5
    end
  end
  Object.const_set( gate_class_name, gate_class )

  type { gate_class_name }
  country { FFaker::Address.country_code }
end
```

Code gave me error when ran with rspec in line "Object.const_set"

```
TypeError: #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Implicit:0x00000006a1af30 @name=:gate_class_name, @ignored=false, @factory=#<FactoryGirl::Definition:0x00000006ed6df8 @declarations=#<FactoryGirl::DeclarationList:0x00000006ed6dd0 @declarations=[#<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Dynamic:0x00000006ed6998 @name=:name, @ignored=false, @block=#<Proc:0x00000006ed69c0@[skipped]>>, #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Implicit:0x00000006a1af30 ...>], @name=:gate, @overridable=false>, @callbacks=[#<FactoryGirl::Callback:0x00000006ed6a38 @name=:before_create, @block=#<Proc:0x00000006ed6ba0@[skipped]>>], @defined_traits=#<Set: {}>, @to_create=nil, @base_traits=[], @additional_traits=[], @constructor=nil, @attributes=nil, @compiled=false>> is not a symbol nor a string
```

but works ok in rails console

Usually I call FactoryGirl factories for creating objects, but, if that is impossible - I wonder for any other method to do that.

Any help is very much appreciate.

Comment: not sure, why do you need special classes for tests. Can't you use those already existing ones?

Comment: Perhaps, you're using STI incorrectly?

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable. Put that in the question.

Comment: Those new derived classes, when hardcoded in app - have to connect to real external services. Here I want to test some usage, without connecting to external world.

Comment: I found that code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302187/ruby-string-to-class-name

Comment: you could stub code that calls external world. `allow(gate).to receive(:fetch_commission_or_whatever).and_return(0.05)`

Comment: Also you could use VCR to record and replay responses from external services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I spend about two hours before posting the question, but I found answer only after posting =)

I had just to move the class definition inside attribute's one.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :gate do

    name { FFaker::Company.name }
    type { 
      class_name = 'Gate' + name.gsub( /[[:blank:][:cntrl:][:punct:]]/,'' ).to_s.singularize
      gate_class = class_name.classify
      class_instance  = Class.new(Gate) do
        def comission_in(amount)
          amount * 0.01 + 5
        end
        def comission_out(amount)
          amount * 0.02 + 5
        end
      end
      Object.const_set( gate_class, class_instance )
      puts " gate_class: '#{ gate_class }'; name: '#{ name }';"
      class_name
    }
    country { FFaker::Address.country_code }

  end
end
```